# Finding DAU/MAU ratio in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

There's a table with customerID, timestamp, activity columns and I found DAU(DailyActiveUsers) and MAU(MonthlyActiveUsers) from this table. Now I need to find DAU/MAU. The problem is I got DAU and MAU as two separate queries as they both need to be grouped by day and month respectively.

Also, DAU would be a table since it's grouped by day and would have 30 rows in the table. MAU is just a single number. How can I find DAU/MAU which is apparently a ratio?

My query for DAU

```
select date, count(distinct customerID) as dau
from table
where extract(month from timestamp) = 1 and extract(year from timestamp) = 2020
  and activity = 'opened_the_app'
group by date
```

This gives me dau for all the 31 days in month of january.

Similarly i found MAU by grouping month which gives me a single value for the month of january.

How can I find the DAU/MAU ratio for january?

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can join them together:

```
select d.*, d.dau * 1.0 / m.mau
from (select date, count(distinct customerID) as dau
      from table
      where timestamp >= '2020-01-01' and
            timestamp < '2020-02-01' and 
            activity = 'opened_the_app'
      group by date
     ) d cross join
     (select count(distinct customerID) as mau
      from table
      where timestamp >= '2020-01-01' and
            timestamp < '2020-02-01' and 
            activity = 'opened_the_app'
     ) m
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find it from the DAU table itself since the MAU will be the sum of DAU

```
select dau/sum(dau) as result from (
        select date, count(distinct customerID) as dau
        from table
        where extract(month from timestamp) = 1 and extract(year from timestamp) = 2020
        and activity = 'opened_the_app'
    ) dau_table
```